# Visual Studio C++ ofstream can't creat .txt files but it can create other types

Tags: c++, visual-studio, fstream, ofstream

My problem is that in this specific drive, visual studio C++ refuses create .txt files using `ofstream` or `fstream` the worst part is this is only targeting .txt extension I can create the file with any extension except .txt.

I am able to create .txt file in another drive(able to with both`ofstream` and `fstream`) . The drive I'm unable to create a text document in is a HDD that got split into 2 partitions, and the one I am able to create a text document on is jsut an SSD that's not split. Visual Studio is installed on my C drive which is also an SSD.

Please help, I'm desperate.

This is the code I'm using to test.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ofstream file("filename.p");
    file << "1";
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: Most likely not a problem with `(o)fstream` itself, but with the OS/filesystem instead. Maybe the file in question is being blocking by an antivirus/anti-malware? Or maybe the file is simply not being created where you are expecting, since you are using a *relative* path (hint: always use *absolute* paths). Try using a tool like [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to watch the file creation at the system level and see what is actually happening.

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: it is antivirus which blocks file creation of .txt files. So just add the whole directory of your project to the exceptions.